# Hedge return of foreign asset

Tags: fx, derivation

Given that $S(T)$ is the value of an asset in a foreign currency, $X(T)$ is the spot domestic/foreign rate, $P_t$ is the value of a Portfolio in the the domestic currency (invested in $S$) and $z^{f}$ and $z^{d}$ are Discount Factors (foreign and domestic),
could somebody explain me what $P_t$ is, given that $ \frac{dP_t}{P_t} =\frac{dS_t}{S_t} +\frac{dX_t}{X_t} +\frac{dX_t}{X_t} \cdot \frac{dS_t}{S_t} - \frac{dX_t}{X_t} + \frac{z^{f,t+dt}}{z^{d,t+dt}}-1$.

The porfolio is overlayed with a FX Forward contract in which one agrees to sell forward $S(t)$ of the foreign currency and buy the domestic currency at $t+dt$.

I know that it starts with $P_t^d  = S_t \cdot X_t$. However, there is the part with the overlay missing. How does that look like?
I hope my question is clear. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Your equation looks a bit odd. Do $+\frac{dX_t}{X_t}$ and $-\frac{dX_t}{X_t}$ cancel each other out? It there a typographical error?

Comment: I guess that the last two terms are used to replace the dx/x part, in some way it makes sense - but I’ve never seen such a formulation til today …

Comment: Eventually they cancel each other out, yes. I left it as it might be easier to work back what the overlay part looks like. Using Ito the derivative of $P_t^d = S_t \cdot X_t$ is $\frac{dS_t}{S_t} +\frac{dX_t}{X_t}+ \frac{dS_t}{S_t} \cdot \frac{dX_t}{X_t}$. But then there is the derivative of the overlay missing.